# Bulk exporting scores from Prediction.io

Tags: predictionio

We are using `Prediction.IO` for our recommendation Engine.

After it is deployed (pio deploy), we can call the web service, it has created after deploying, to get the recommendation results one user at a time when needed. We can also send many requests in a single call for many users.

Because we have billions of events and 100s of millions of user entities, using the web service from the http port is not a fast way to export the data and analyse it, say, in Hive.

The problem is, we could not find a way to export the recommendations for all users (let us say 10 recommendations for each user).

There is a command (pio export) to export all the event data, but this does not contain the score values or the recommendation results.

Any thoughts on finding a way to bulk export the results?

Answer (score 1):

After some research found [this](https://docs.prediction.io/templates/recommendation/evaluation/) on PredictionIO web site;

> This how-to tutorial would explain how you can also use $pio eval to persist predicted result for a batch of queries. Please read the Evaluation to understand the usage of DataSoure's readEval() and the Evaluation component first.

Also;

> This tutorial is based on some experimental and developer features, which may be changed in future release.